# How to impute the missing value or value having 0 with the average of two nearby non-zero values in Pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to impute the missing value or value having 0 with the average of two nearby non-zero values in Pandas in python shown in this Image

[image: How to impute the missing value or value having 0 with the average of two nearby non-zero values in Pandas in python shown in this Image]

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to replace the `0` with `None`, and then use `.bfill()` and `.ffill()` on the column in question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'b': [1, 2, 0, 0, 5]})
df.loc[df['b']==0]=None
df['b'] = (df['b'].ffill()+df['b'].bfill())*0.5

   a    b
0  a  1.0
1  b  2.0
2  c  3.5
3  d  3.5
4  e  5.0
```